# Ionic app cache not clearing while app update

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

We had released a new version ionic 1 app with entire backend rewamp. But on updation data is not clearing and the app is crashing. However if we clear app data manually its working fine. Kindly suggest solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: you need more help? bcoz you haven't accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of your data is being changed, you will have to clear the data. For this, you need to use a key like `hardCacheRefrehDone`. Check this key and if not present, clear the cache in whichever way you have stored the data. And then set the `hardCacheRefrehDone` key to `true`. So this way, next time when app runs, it will not clear the data again.

You might even want to change the format of the existing data to your new format, so in that case, you can retrieve them and store in new way.

```
if(!this.hardCacheRefreshDone) {
  // clear the data here
  // change data to newer format
  // set the key to true using storage or whichever method you are using
}
```

PS: `hardCacheRefrehDone` is just a suggestion, you can use any key name

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know :

Comment: I would suggest not to clear the data directly, rather try to convert them to new format. This will help you maintain the app state for the user.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case we dont have access to older version code and storage keys. We just need a full reset of data

Comment: We are trying to do that but its not clearing on update. Only partial data is getting cleared

Comment: You might be storing data from different places and may be missing some to clear something

Comment: Overall, this is the approach and you can accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: The issue was due to tables not getting deleted anyways thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, if the table structure is also changed, then they also needs to be deleted

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: yes we had changed the table structure a bit which was causing the issue

Comment: let me know if any more help needed